# extends does not work my entity with a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a entity, for example, "MovieDetails" and inside this entity there is a array about their ratings...

When I'm building my infra and I must create a model and do mapped to this entity, something wrong my model...

Entity

```
class ResultMovieDetailsEntity {
  String title;
  String poster;
  List<ResultMoviesRatings> ratings;

ResultMovieDetailsEntity(
      {
   this.title,
   this.poster,
   this.ratings
     });
```

My model have this same properties and methods from Json and tojsons....
But, when in my model I did a extends, show me a error.

error:

> List ratings
> package:arch_example_movies/infra/models/result_movie_details_model.dart
>
> 'ResultMovieDetailsModel.ratings=' ('void
> Function(List)') isn't a valid override of
> 'ResultMovieDetailsEntity.ratings=' ('void
> Function(List)').dartinvalid_override

someone can help me?

Comment: Can you show how you're creating the instace of `ResultMovieDetailsEntity`? it seems you're not building with correct parameters

Comment: of course, in my github, I put my entitys and my models. 
    my git: https://github.com/bersot1/arch_study

Comment: I don't see any extend in that github.. why don't you paste here the exact code that is failing for you?

Comment: I did want facilitate for you and left only files that matter, but I push all project.